# CDF of standard norm dist random variable by division?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this exercise with a title: *Inverse CDF method and Cauchy distribution*.

Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{a + x^2}$., where $α > 0$ is a constant such that $ \int_{}^{}f(x) dx = 1$. Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution admits $f$ for the density of probability.

Question 1: Calculate, for all real $x$, the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of $X$.

Question 2: Using the inverse cumulative distribution function method, write a function $cauchy( N )$ that simulates $N$ independent random variables having the same distribution as $X$.

My questions:

1. How does $f$ relate to Cauchy distribution.
2. What does `having the same distribution as $X$` mean exactly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you said this was an exercise, I won't be providing the direct calculations.

Question 1:
So, if you look at the definiton of the Cauchy distribution, its pdf is given by

$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi \gamma (1 + \frac{x-x_0}{\gamma})^2}$

so basically you can just match terms to see that you can write the function you have as a Cauchy distribution up to a normalization term. In either case, for the second part you will need the cdf so you could also just go about and directly calculate the cdf

$F_X(x) = C\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(x) $

noting that your pdf can be written as a derivative of the arctan-function, you'll arrive at the cdf. Here, C is a normalization factor which you will have to calculate.

Question 2:
You can generate random variables by inverting the cdf. This is based on that $F_X(x) \in [0,1]$ so that you can then draw samples $x$ by solving $x = F_X^{-1}(P)$ where $P \sim U[0,1]$. E.g. for a exponentially distributed random variable $Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$, one has that

$F_Y(y) = 1 - e^{-\lambda y}$

So if we let $P \sim U[0,1]$, you can invert the cdf to obtain

$y = -\frac{1}{\lambda} ln(1-P) = -\frac{1}{\lambda} ln(P) $

Now do this for the cdf you calculate in the first question. It should be simple enough to invert.